# Spring RestTemplate or HttpClient 4.3.x not passing compressed data through Authenticated Proxy

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

Trying to use HttpClient and Spring to go through a Proxy Server.  Lots of questions and help on this.  However, I need to send COMPRESSED data over a REST call.  Currently, it is working fine without a Proxy.  Additinally, I see from the access logs that it passes through the Proxy (unauthenticated) fine as well.  Here is some data from the access logs (here using Squid3, but get this same behavior with other Proxies too)

```
1449876389.237      9 10.1.10.100 TCP_MISS/204 297 POST http://mymachine.domain.com:8080/j_spring_security_check - DIRECT/10.1.0.16 -
1449876389.377     16 10.1.10.100 TCP_MISS/201 1458 POST http://mymachine.domain.com:8080/api/items - DIRECT/10.1.0.16 application/json
1449876390.727      9 10.1.10.100 TCP_MISS/204 222 POST http://mymachine.domain.com:8080/j_spring_security_check - DIRECT/10.1.0.16 -
1449876391.031    241 10.1.10.100 TCP_MISS/201 1492 PUT http://mymachine.domain.com:8080/api/items/8fee3734-39ee-43eb-8009-6308d5c1aff1 - DIRECT/10.1.0.16 application/json
```

The key line is the last one - the data was compressed to 1492, an HTTPStatus of 201 was returned.  Without changing the software, simply defining the system settings to point to an Authenticated (digest) Proxy Server, these lines are seen instead:

```
1449876352.292     44 10.1.10.100 TCP_MISS/201 1403 POST http://mymachine.domain.com:8080/api/items myuser DIRECT/10.1.0.16 application/json
1449876353.782      0 10.1.10.100 TCP_DENIED/407 4151 POST http://mymachine.domain.com:8080/j_spring_security_check - NONE/- text/html
1449876353.795     11 10.1.10.100 TCP_MISS/204 222 POST http://mymachine.domain.com:8080/j_spring_security_check myuser DIRECT/10.1.0.16 -
1449876353.853      0 10.1.10.100 TCP_DENIED/407 4239 PUT http://mymachine.domain.com:8080/api/items/3b505ae1-dc0c-4432-8604-8a107ab30bc6 - NONE/- text/html
```

Note that this time, the data appears uncompressed (4239) which results in an HTTPStatus of 407.  Further not that the content-type appears as text/html and NOT as application/json.  I am using Spring 4.1.x and HttpClient 4.3.6.  Does anyone know how to correct this behavior and make it work?

I believe the code used follows a fairly common pattern for going through a Proxy Server.  It is shown below.  I have tried many variants (commenting out the set proxy in one or both locations, forcing the content-type to be 'application/json', etc).  Not knowing the cause makes finding the solution to this particular problem impossible!   FINALLY, what might be one of the most important facts: very small contents work also work completely successfully with the authenticated Proxy, it is only when the PUT size gets over 4K - 6K (not that that is big!), that the failures (407s) start to happen - and they happen every time.

```
HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
httpClientBuilder.useSystemProperties();
String proxyUsername = System.getProperty("http.proxyUser", "");
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(proxyUsername)) {
    String proxyPassword = System.getProperty("http.proxyPassword", "");
    String scheme = StringUtils.isNotBlank(System.getProperty("http.proxyHost", "")) ? "http" : "https";
    String proxyHost = System.getProperty("http.proxyHost",
                System.getProperty("https.proxyHost", ""));
    String proxyPortStr = System.getProperty("http.proxyPort",
                System.getProperty("https.proxyPort", ""));
    Integer proxyPort = Integer.decode(proxyPortStr);

    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort, scheme);
    httpClientBuilder.setProxy(proxy);
    DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
    httpClientBuilder.setRoutePlanner(routePlanner);
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPort),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUsername, proxyPassword));

    httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
}
HttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
```